# Regex Javascript Phone number validation min max length check

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want a very simple Regex for Javascript validation of phone number, which allows `10 digits` and checks `min numbers should be 10 and max 12` including `- dash two times` for ex. `123-123-1234`

I have found some on internet, but none of them is working for `min / max length`.

Looking forward for quick response here.

Thanks !

Comment: A good answer to this question should explain that this expression is not possible and suggest workarounds. An excellent answer would provide such an expression.

Comment: yes but any idea in mind that will work with `min/max length check` n said validation?

Comment: My phone number has 13 characters, one of which is a `+`… be very careful that if you are restricting phone numbers you aren't going to reject real ones used by the people using your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this

```
/^(?!.*-.*-.*-)(?=(?:\d{8,10}$)|(?:(?=.{9,11}$)[^-]*-[^-]*$)|(?:(?=.{10,12}$)[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$)  )[\d-]+$/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?309q8)

`(?!...)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)

`(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)

```
^                                          # Start of the string
    (?!.*-.*-.*-)                          # Fails if there are more than 2 dashes
    (?=(?:\d{8,10}$)                   # if only digits to the end, then length 8 to 10
        |(?:(?=.{9,11}$)[^-]*-[^-]*$)  # if one dash, then length from 9 to 11
        |(?:(?=.{10,12}$)
            [^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$         # if two dashes, then length from 10 to 12
         )
    )
[\d-]+                                     # match digits and dashes (your rules are done by the assertions)
$                                          # the end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

What you asking for wouldn't be a simple regular expression and also may be solved without any use 'em.

```
function isPhoneNumberValid(number){
  var parts, len = (
    parts = /^\d[\d-]+\d$/g.test(number) && number.split('-'),
    parts.length==3 && parts.join('').length
  );
  return (len>=10 && len<=12)
}
```

For sure this may be a bit slower than using a compiled regex, but overhead is way minor if you not going to check hundreds of thousandths phone numbers this way.

This isn't perfect in any way but may fit your needs, beware however that this allow two dashes in any place excluding start and end of number, so this will return `true` for string like `111--123123`.

Answer (score -1):

There's no simple way to do this with regexp, especially if you allow dashes to appear at some different points.

If you allow dashes only at places as in your example, then it would be `^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$`

This one: `^[\d-]{10,12}$` matches string with length from 10 to 12 and contains only digits and dashes, but it also will match e.g. `-1234567890-`.

Comment: but does this apply for `min / max length` check? I am not sure this will work for length check

Comment: This one allows strings like `123-123-1234` or `123123-1234` or `123-1231234` or `1231231234` and that implies among others, that length is always 10-12. There's no way to directly check length of the string and some criteria about its chars within one regex.